# What is the difference between na.omit and is.na?

Tags: r

What is the difference between `na.omit` and `is.na`?

```
minO2 <- equal.count(na.omit(algae$mnO2),number=4,overlap=1/5)
stripplot(season ~ a3|minO2,data=algae[!is.na(algae$mnO2),])
```

I used `na.omit` instead of `is.na` in second code line? and I got totally different plot.

Another thing is that if you someone tell me the logic behind the `!` (logical negation operator), I will be appreciated?

Comment: Did you actually replace `is.na` with `na.omit`, resulting in `algae[!na.omit(algae$mn02),]`?

Comment: you forgot to mention that `equal.count` and `stripplot` are in package `lattice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the call to `equal.count`, the object `na.omit(algae$mnO2)` will be those values in `algae$mn02` that are not `NA`.

Now, say that you have this code for the plot:

```
stripplot(season ~ a3|minO2,data=na.omit(algae))
```

If there are any columns of `algae` that contain `NA` in rows where `algae$mn02` is not `NA`, the rows will not line up, and the plot will not be as expected.

Here's an example where this will happen:

```
algae<- data.frame(a3=c(NA,1,2), mn02=c(1,2,NA))
algae
##   a3 mn02
## 1 NA    1
## 2  1    2
## 3  2   NA
```

Note the difference between the following two expressions:

```
na.omit(algae)
##   a3 mn02
## 2  1    2

algae[!is.na(algae$mn02),]
##   a3 mn02
## 1 NA    1
## 2  1    2
```

The latter will line up with the shingle produced by `equal.count(na.omit(algae$mn02))` but the former will not.  The first expression here has one less row because there is an incomplete case where `mn02` is not `NA`.

Note:

```
equal.count(na.omit(algae$mn02))
## 
## Data:
## [1] 1 2
```

...

There are two elements here.  This expression does not check for `NA` in columns other than `mn02`.

Answer (score 2):

Set up the data

```
nas <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3, NA)
```

`is.na` returns a logial vector

```
is.na(nas)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The `!` operator will take the trues and make them falses and turn the falses into trues.

```
!(is.na(nas))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Which returns the negation of `is.na(nas)`

`na.omit` removes the the NA's from the vector

```
na.omit(tf)
[1] 1 2 3
```

I can't tell what's happening with your plots without a bit more information.

Comment: Thanks for helpful your explanation.