# lapply ignore NA

Tags: r, lapply, na

Hi I want to normalize on column of my data set-trainingData[1].  the type of this column is num. But When I run the code below, it gave me all NA, is that because there is NA in my dataset, and how can I tell lapply to ignore it.

```
normalize <- function(x) {
    return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

trainingData[1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(trainingData[1], normalize))
```

Thank you!

Comment: you could call the `min()` and `max()` functions setting the argument `na.rm = TRUE`. Example:  `min(c(NA, 2:4), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 normalize <- function(x) {
                  return ((x - min(x,na.rm=T)) / (max(x,na.rm=T) - min(x,na.rm=T)))
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build in a `is.na()` filter into into your `normalize()` function:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
   #first option
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
   #second option
    #x <- na.omit(x)
    return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: For your use case, no. But there can be alignment issues with subsetting dataframes. Here's a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493447/what-is-the-difference-between-na-omit-and-is-na

Comment: Thank you. Btw, my model's accuracy dropped after the feature scaling, is this possible?

Comment: It is possible. It also depends on what your model is. Normalizing and transforming the range of possible inputs to [0,1] means all inputs columns are equally weighted. So `age` (measured in integer years) and `annual salary` (on a scale of $10,000s) will be equally weighted when unnormalized `annual salary` would dominate during training. Perhaps your data is more informative with the current weighting now.

Comment: Gotta Thank you!